# Google plus share wrong Title , Url

Tags: google-plus, meta

I try every tag follow og and schema.org meta

**Inner pages**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="xxx" />
<meta itemprop="name" content="xxx">
<meta itemprop="description" content="xxx">
<meta itemprop="image" content="xxx">
<link itemprop="url" href="xxx">

<h1 itemprop="name">xxx</h1>
```

But when i share , wrong title , url is wrong .

It use data index page , I want data inner page
But link in top https now Rigth

[Now it display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vUum.jpg)

[image]